# How can I unlock a non system Mac OS X 10.5.8 drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, file-permissions

I have just had to reinstall OS 10.5.8 on my G4 tower (I'm using it as a file server/auxiliary machine)  I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it but, I have another internal drive in the machine and I can't get access to it. I have tried using the get info window but it won't retain any changes I make.

**Notes**:

- The second drive is recognized I'm just locked out from seeing the contents. Can't read or write. Also disk utility does recognize it. I have verified the disk using disk tools and it has not had any errors.
- Here's a screenshot of the get info window of the drive (the user names look messed up too).

[image]

Comment: As your question stands now, it is unclear what you are asking.  Is your second internal HDD unrecognized? Unreadable? Unwritable?  Please be more specific.

Comment: Does the second internal drive appear in Disk Utility?

Comment: Found BatChmod at http://www.lagentesoft.com/batchmod/index.html and it was an easy fix to my issue!